# How to change the color of a label of an ion-input in ionic 7

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, sass, ionic6, ionic7

I have upgraded my project to Ionic 7 and now ion-inputs don't need an ion-label. I have changed it but I don't know how to assign the color they had.

Before:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yrrV.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8rqD.png)

After:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vGfl.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6Fjf.png)

I can't find anything related in the documentation. Can someone help me??

Comment: Please don't post code as image - paste the actual code and format it for better readability and better chance to get an answer. Anyway, I still didn't move to ionic 7, but there must be some shadow DOM selector you could use to access the label of the ion-input. Check css classes assigned to parts of ion-input and try to target them specifically. Also, experiment with ::part() to see what you can catch. I am also interested to see the real answer.

Answer (score 4):

Took a little bit of trial and error but this is what I have found to change the label part of ion-input in ionic7:

css:

```
::ng-deep ion-input .label-text{
    color: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <ion-item>
        <ion-input labelPlacement="stacked" value="hi@ionic.io">
          <div slot="label"> <ion-text color="danger"> Email (Required)</ion-text></div>
        </ion-input>
   </ion-item>
```

Comment: use of "slot" for labels is still considered experimental in Ionic 7

Answer (score 0):

Two other options without the deprecated `::ng-deep` selector:

### a) Use class names and add a global stylesheet with colors:

```
/* should be in a global stylesheet i.e. styles.css */
ion-input.red label .label-text {
  color: 'red';
}
```

Use in your `my.component.html` like this:

```
<ion-input labelPlacement="fixed" class="red"></ion-input>
```

### b) Use the --color variable in your component stylesheet:

This option is also mentioned [here in the Ionic documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input#colors).

You can set the `--color` variable inside your component stylesheet to the desired color.

```
/* my.component.css */
:host ion-input {
  // change the text label for all ion-input elements inside this component to red.
  --color: red
}
```

Or wrap it in an additional class in case you want to have several options:

```
/* my.component.css */
:host ion-input.red {
  // change the text label for ion-input elements with classname red inside this component to red.
  --color: red
}
```

Use in your `my.component.html` like this:

```
<ion-input labelPlacement="fixed" class="red"></ion-input>
```